# How to restrict access in Passport Client Credentials grant type when we have multiple clients

Tags: laravel, api, oauth, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I want to provide API for two banks (machine to machine). AFAIK the best grant type for this purpose is Client Credentials. But how can I restrict bank A to access only ControllerA and bank B to access only ControllerB?

it doesn't seem right to create two user for these banks!

Comment: You can setup route group and set prefix in route and namespace for different bank. You can encrypt() and decrypt() the route prefix so user cant change the URL.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use middleware (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes) like the ‘checkRole’ example and optionally, use token scopes (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#token-scopes), to protect your routes.

Comment: Thanks, in `checkRole` we have a logged-in user but in client credentials grant type we do not have a logged-in user and `$request->user()` is null. token-scope doesn't work because the bank will assign the scope to itself!

Comment: What do you mean the bank will assign "the scope" to itself? You don't have to use middleware only for checking logged in users. You can use it to check anything on the request including, for example, the token and its scope.